# Max XOR of two elements in an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I was looking for some efficient algorithm for calculating Maximum xor value you can get by XORing any two values of an array.

For example, if i and j are indices of the array then you have to maximize (Ai xor Aj)...

I found two efficient approaches one of them uses tries and one algorithm which I found on LeetCode which promises results in O(nlog(U)) U is the number of bits in array elements.

This algorithm is working properly However, I am having problems in understanding why and how it's working.

Here is the code snippet

```
int findMaximumXOR(vector<int>& nums) {
    int mask = 0;
    int test_max = 0;
    int max = 0;
    unordered_set<int> s;
    for(long long i = 30; i >= 0; --i){
        mask |= 1ll << i;

        printf("\n"BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_BINARY(mask));

        for(int num : nums){
            s.insert(num & mask);
        }

        test_max = max | 1 << i;
        for(int s_val : s){
            if(s.find(s_val ^ test_max) != s.end()){
                max = test_max;
                break;
            }
        }
        s.clear();
    }
    return max;
}
```

** There is already a question on stack-overflow with the same title but they discussed only the tries approach

Comment: what is exactly "maximum xor possible of two numbers"?

Comment: Maximum xor value you can get by xoring any two values of array. like if i and j are indices than you have to maximize (Ai xor Aj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function calculate the max number represented by XOR(a,b).
To calculate this, it goes from the most significant bit to the least.
In the first iteration it checks if there are to numbers who differ in the most significant bit. After each iteration it keeps the max XOR of the prefix between two numbers and than checks if there are two numbers who have that distance and also differ in the next bit.
s is a set of the prefixes of the numbers, test_max is the max XOR of the prefixes.
this section:

```
test_max = max | 1 << i;
for(int s_val : s){
    if(s.find(s_val ^ test_max) != s.end()){
        max = test_max;
        break;
    }
}
```

tries to increase the prefix by one bit by checking if there are two numbers who keeps the max XOR prefix and also differ by the next bit.
EDIT:
As I understand from the code, the Max XOR is maximum of `(int)(a[i]^a[j])`.